# remove double qoute from string at first and last position or convert string to some other datatype type

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to Remove first and last double quote

> "  [["January", 10], ["February", 8], ["March", 4], ["April", 13], ["May", 17], ["June", 9]]  "

To

> [["January", 10], ["February", 8], ["March", 4], ["April", 13], ["May", 17], ["June", 9]]

**Reason :**

To show above data in chart I have used webservice that return string.

Now for jsChart data needs without string double quote at 1st and last position.

**What I had Tried :**

```
data=data.replace(/^"(.+(?="$))"$/, '$1');
```

or

```
data=data.substring(1,data.length-1);
```

all above return with double quote.

Comment: First of all double or single quotations are _methods_ used by javascript to indicate a _string value_, so they are not part of a string but rather a **container**, for that reason **they can not be removed**. secondly If I'm not wrong jsChart data accepts javascript arrays, not a strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, jsChart data requires a javascript array, not a string without the first and last quote (what by the way doesn't make any sense).

So, what you have to do is:

First, get a proper js string from your webservice such as:

```
var str = '[["January", 10], ["February", 8], ["March", 4], ["April", 13], ["May", 17], ["June", 9]]';// Note the single quotes to wrap strings that contain double quotes
```

Second, transform this string in a javascript array:

```
var data = JSON.parse(str);
```

Use `data` in your jsChart. BTW, I think jsChart `data` needs to be an array of objects, and the array you provided isn't an array of objects so I think you'll need to tamper a little bit more to get things to work.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = '"[["January", 10], ["February", 8], ["March", 4], ["April", 13], ["May", 17], ["June", 9]]"';
    data = data.substring(1, data.length-1);
alert(data);
```